# how to get drag/drop event on listitem of listbox in zk framework

Tags: java, zk

I am writing drag and drop functionality using two listBox using java class. I have implemented two scenarios.

1. the listitem A is add at the bottom of the listitem B
2. If I have already selected a listitem in B, When I drop the item in
   the list, it is added at that location

My requirement is more close to 2. i.e. I don't have to pre-select the item list, and the item list from A should be moved to the index where mouse points (like mouse over effect). I am unable to find any such method in `Listbox` or `Listitem` which would give me that location.

Following is the code which is working in case of 2.

```
droppedListbox.insertBefore(draggedListitem, droppedListbox.getSelectedItem());
```

In above code, second parameter should be the mouse highlighted `Listitem` as it happens in demo application which is using zul files.

As I mentioned previously, I want to move the item to selected place in `Listitem` B. For that I have to made these changes into my zul file.

```
<listbox id="adminListbox" droppable="true" draggable="true" model="${win$composer.systemAdminListModel}" width="330px" height="100%" oddRowSclass="non-odd">
.
.
.
<template name="model">
<listitem draggable="true" droppable="true">
<listcell label="${each.id}" ></listcell>
<listcell label="${each.name}" ></listcell>
<listcell label="${each.role}" ></listcell>
</listitem>
</template> [added dropable to listitem]
```

Now my java code which is as follows is not being activated on drop the item on `Listitem` B.:

```
@Listen("onDrop = #userListbox")
public void onDragDropUserListitem(){
}
```

If I remove droppable from listitem, then it's being called. But to move the listitem to that location, I have to add droppable true here. I would also mention that the listitem is dynamic so I can't give it a id to attache a @wire and get it's event.

I want to know how to get an event on listitem in java, so that I can perform any action on it. In current sceario my event "onDrop" is not being called.

Here is event method

```
@Listen("onDrop = #userListbox")
public void onDragDropUserListitem(DropEvent dropEvent){

    userListbox.addEventListener("onDrop", new EventListener<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {

            Listbox droppedListbox = (Listbox)(((DropEvent)event).getTarget());
            Listitem draggedListitem = (Listitem)((DropEvent)event).getDragged();

            if (draggedListitem instanceof Listitem) {    
                droppedListbox.insertBefore(draggedListitem, droppedListbox.getNextSibling());
            } else {
                droppedListbox.appendChild(draggedListitem);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the zul complete component

```
<listbox id="userListbox"  droppable="true" model="${win$composer.systemUserListModel}"  width="330px" height="100%" oddRowSclass="non-odd">
    <listhead>
        <listheader label="User ID" align="center" />
        <listheader label="User Name" align="center" />
        <listheader label="User Role" align="center" />
    </listhead>
    <template name="model">
        <listitem draggable="true" droppable="true" >
            <listcell label="${each.id}" />
            <listcell label="${each.name}" />
            <listcell label="${each.role}" />
        </listitem>
    </template>
</listbox>
```

I hope its all you need and if you remove, droppable from listitem, it works fine but not my requirement.

Comment: Please take a look at the preview and format your anwsers better.

Comment: I think the first problem is, that you do not understand how droppable/dragable is working. if you write dragable="test" in item A and droppable="test" in item B then you can drag A on B. ture means no limitation. Item here means every component in your .zul file. And better write public void onDragDropUserListitem(DropEvent event).

Comment: thank you nabil and i know what you just said and i am able to do the drag and drop using java which adds the item list at the bottom. if you have seen drag drop example on zk demo, i just want to add that using using java. problem is, can't get the event in above scenario to manipulate itemlist. do you have any solution for my requirements ???

Comment: Pleas provide more code. I need to see more of the Composer, where it is applyed and the complete code between the opening and colseing xml tag of the component to which the Composer is applyed would be perfect.

Comment: well, i could do that if i can, this line gives me listbox: Listbox droppedListbox = (Listbox)(((DropEvent)event).getTarget());, so i have to do this way, i can't reach at the listitem level

Comment: I am not sure whats your point but maybe my edit helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the first problem is

```
@Listen("onDrop = #userListbox")
public void onDragDropUserListitem(DropEvent dropEvent){

    userListbox.addEventListener("onDrop", new EventListener<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
```

in this code each time you drop you add an EventListener, cos you add an EventListener in an Eventlistener.

```
@Listen("onDrop = #userListbox")
public void onDragDropUserListitem(DropEvent dropEvent){
      Listbox droppedListbox = (Listbox)dropEvent.getTarget());
      Listitem draggedListitem = (Listitem)dropEvent.getDragged();

            if (draggedListitem instanceof Listitem) {

                droppedListbox.insertBefore(draggedListitem, droppedListbox.getNextSibling());

            }else{
                droppedListbox.appendChild(draggedListitem);
            }

}
```

this should work better.

The next thing is, i do not see anything like `apply="ComposerName"` i hope do this.
If you do so in a higher Component, it's better to add the complete path to the Component
 after the `=` in your `@Listen("onDrop = #userListbox")`.
[Klick here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/January/Envisage_ZK_6%3a_An_Annotation_Based_Composer_For_MVC#Syntax) to see howto do so.
But now, this code is a problem

```
Listbox droppedListbox = (Listbox)dropEvent.getTarget();
Listitem draggedListitem = (Listitem)dropEvent.getDragged();
```

cos the traget can be `Listbox` as well as `Listitem` you should handle this.

In this step you can add the code for your expecting order as well.
Just add the `draggedListitem` to the `userListbox` before or after the `droppedListitem`
or at the end of the list if `getTarget()` is `Listbox`, by calling the insertion methods of `userListbox`.

### EDIT

But `@Listen("onDrop = #userListbox")` just listen at the `Listbox`, but we want to listen to the `Listitem`s as well.

Your final code could look like this

```
@Listen("onDrop = #userListbox")
public void onDragDropUserListbox(DropEvent dropEvent) {
    userListbox.appendChild(dropEvent.getTarget());
}

@Listen("onDrop = listitem")
public void onDragDropUserListitem(DropEvent dropEvent) {
    Listitem droppedListitem = (Listitem) dropEvent.getTarget();
    Listitem draggedListitem = (Listitem) dropEvent.getDragged();

    userListbox.insertBefore(draggedListitem, droppedListitem);
}
```

I have tested this and it adds the dragged element before the element it is dropped to.

Comment: thank you but it's not what i want (i have checked it), my old code is also able to drag and drop at the bottom of the listbox, i want to add it on a location in list where i drop it using java code.

Comment: Oh myyy! Of Course i was so focused on the method that i did not see the Listener was wrong. I will edit it.

Comment: final code, first method, doesn't work, it's gives error for syntex, you can remove that from solution, with second option using 2 methods, the drop from A to B was done on specified location. Now there is another issue, when i drop the same object to shuffle the listitem in the list box as happening in demo example, i am getting "Unable to add component with the same parent: <Listitem oWCPu0>", can you please look into it too please ?

Comment: Hi Nabil, you solution worked, i just have to remove and remove the shuffle component in the itemlist, its working fine now. Thank you so much for your great help.